# OpenGL quads overlapping

Tags: opengl, gpu

Say I have two quads which are overlapping, forming an X.

Is it possible to disable this from happening? So that the GPU removes (one of) these overlapping quads?

The case is about billboards, which *shine* through the static walls. In a ideal case, I would wan't to have the billboard removed when it overlaps with the wall, without spending a lot of CPU utilisation on it (I have about 10.000 billboards and walls).

Currently my billboards are implemented by calculating the angle between object and camera.

Answer (score 3):

> Currently my billboards are implemented by calculating the angle between object and camera.

Totally wrong approach. The usual OpenGL perspective projection is a plane parallel one. So this means that you normally want your billboard to be coplanar to your near/far cliping plane.

This is most easily done by taking the inverse of the upper left 3×3 part of the world- to eyespace transformation matrix, and use the X any Y columns of this as base vectors for your billboard quads.

As it happens, rotation matrices inverse is the transpose. So just take the first and second row vectors of the camera transformation matrix (only the first 3 elements each) and use them as base for your billboards. Don't mess with triginometry or angles here, you're barking up the wrong tree then.

The overlap is usually taken care of by depth testing. For translucent geometry disable depth writes and pre-sort your geometry far-to-near.

Comment: I need True cylindrical billboarding for my case (3d sprites) as where I think your case doesn't imply. http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/billboarding/index.php3?billCyl

Comment: However if you know how to get 3d sprites nicely working with coplanar to the clipping plane, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: @KajToet: Could you please post a screenshot of your situation?